# Execute java method on JSF button click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

When I click on button nothing happens.

```
 <h:commandButton value="Generate PDF" type="button"
        action="#{parseHtml12.createPdf}" />
```

This button is in XHTML file which I want  convert to pdf.
Java class code is here :

```
public class ParseHtml12 {
    public static final String DEST = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop/report.pdf";
    public static final String HTML = "web/data.xhtml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new ParseHtml12().createPdf(DEST);
    }


    public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        writer.setInitialLeading(12);

        document.open();

        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                new FileInputStream(HTML));

        document.close();
    }
}
```

This code is good , only problem is how execute  class on button click.
When I run class  in IDE gives me the  result  but the problem is that the content in XHTML is dynamic and does not retrieve values.

If I execute class when the value will be filled , this will give me  desired result.

UPDATE: When the button is clicked dynamic data disappear. And if I click once again happens like this:
 `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /data.xhtml @48,45 action="#{parseHtml12.createPdf}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'parseHtml12' resolved to null`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an iText question. As you write yourself, the iText part of code, in Java, is ok when you run it in your IDE, so your problem is isolated in your JSF. I suggest that you remove the iText tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment.

try wrapping your commandButton inside a `<h:form>` tag, and add `type="submit"` to the button.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me start button but when the button is clicked dynamic data disappear. And if I click once again happens like this: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /data.xhtml @48,45 action="#{parseHtml12.createPdf}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'parseHtml12' resolved to null`

Comment: `createPdf`, is a method not an attribute, plus it has a String parameter, it should be `#{parseHtml12.createPdf(the name of your file)}`

Comment: unrelated, try to handle the 2 exceptions in the `createPdf` method, just throwing them is not practical. try `FacesMessage` with `<h:messages>`

Comment: I tried different combinations `#{parseHtml12.createPdf(the name of your file)}` but still the same error

Comment: Thanks had the same issue and your answer solved my problem!